# How to Recursively Search For a pattern among files in directories and subdirectories and generate sha1sum?

Tags: linux, bash, hash

As the title explains i want to recursively search for the files among directory which contains subdirectories with grep-ing for a specific pattern and generate sha1sum of files matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `grep -rl /path -e string` to recursively search a path for the desired string.
then incorporate that into a oneliner like this
`for i in $(grep -rl /path -e string); do sha1sum $i; done`

Comment: there would be a way using find with xargs or exec, but plain grep is the easiest way